# Connection coefficients calculation for covariant derivative operation

Tags: geometry

I have been studying differential geometry for a while. Several concepts build the local structure and operations of a smooth manifold. Among them, the covariant derivative $\nabla$ is a very important operator. Its definition requires the concept of a connection. I was, unfortunately, unable to understand it (my brain skipped this section, and accepted the terms as "Levi-Civita connection", which leads to Christoffel symbols). I was informed by further reading, that these Christoffel symbols are coordinate maps for operations between coordinate vectors $\nabla_{X_i} X_j = \Gamma^k_{ij} X_k$, or in local coordinate frame $\nabla_{e_i} e_j = \nabla_{e_i} e_j = \nabla_i e_j = \Gamma_{ij}$. I also read about its constraint requirements "metric-compatible" and "torsion-free", although I cannot find a reference to it. I (mis-)read Koszul's formula as well, but cannot understand in layman's terms, which is something that bothers me.

It would be nice to know about other famous connections, just to keep informed. Thanks!

Comment: There are many types of connections (Levi-Civita, Bismut, Chern connection etc.).  You may also be interested in the concept of horizontal distribution on principal bundles and connection one-forms.

Comment: Would you recommend some literature or give a brief remark on the subject, please? Just as an introduction... these connections you mention have their "flavors", as I say, the requirements they may fulfill, right!? I do not know them.

Comment: The literature is really wide, you can just google some of the connections I mentioned and look for references. An excellent overview is given in Kobayashi-Nomizu, Foundations of differential geometry (vol. 1 and 2).

Comment: Whipping 250 dollars each.